# android-append element to top of recycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to append a new  row to top of a recycleView . this is my adapter code :

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Items> list;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<Items> feedItemList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list = feedItemList;
    }

    public void addtotop(List<Items> catItems) {
        if (this.list == null) {
            this.list = catItems;
        } else {
            this.list.addAll(0,catItems);
        }
        notifyItemInserted(list.size());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addItem(String s) {
        List<Items> newitems = new ArrayList<>();
        Items item = new Items();
        item.setcomment(s.toString());
        addtotop(newitems);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parrent, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_row, parrent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        Items item = list.get(position);
        viewHolder.dates.setText(item.getdates());
    }
```

It doesn't add the new row until i scroll down a bit and scroll up again to show it .

How to add and show the row right after adding it ?

thanks

Comment: I had a similar situation and I think I wound up having to use `notifyItemRangeChanged` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: Something like `notifyItemRangeChanged(0, list.size() -  1)`

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add new row on the top of RecycleView, please follow this step:

1. Reverse the list data before setAdapter:
   Collections.reverse(yourList);
2. setAdapter for your RecycleView: yourRecycleView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);

That's all